Why does traefik only work if containers are placed into the network traefik_default?
I've inherited some Docker host being used as reverse proxy for a public HTTPS entry-point, so that multiple different webapps can be hosted underneath the same HTTPS entry-point.

https://foo.example.org/app1/ -> http://172.1?.0.2:3010
https://foo.example.org/app2/ -> http://172.1?.0.3:4711

The proxy part is implemented by traefik being hosted as a container with the network traefik_default and 172.18.0.0/16. OTOH, the default Docker network is 172.17.0.0/16 and the routing table looks like the following:
[...]@[...]:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens160
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-9628d8a7c930
192.168.131.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160

[...]@[...]:~$ ip route show
default via 192.168.131.254 dev ens160 proto static
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-9628d8a7c930 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1
192.168.131.0/24 dev ens160 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.131.151

[...]@[...]:~$ traceroute 172.17.0.3
traceroute to 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3)  0.050 ms  0.005 ms  0.003 ms

[...]@[...]:~$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

What I've recognized is that things work or don't work as expected depending on in which network the containers are started. If it's the default Docker 172.17, things don't work. Traefik is unable to forward requests and runs into errors like HTTP status 499, that client closed the connection or gateway timeouts etc. None of that seems related to the browser, but to traefik itself.
Though, it properly logs creation of routers, services etc., tells things about setting up services in 172.17.0.2 with the configured ports etc. No errors about wrong networks, that ports are already in use or anything like that. OTOH, when the container is just placed into the network 172.18, things instantly work always and traefik logs the same things, only with different IPs.
My expectation was that as long as routing and stuff is correct, traefik is able to reach the container IPs and ports, it doesn't matter in which network the container runs. But that's not the case and I don't see routing errors. Additionally, by accident I found the following docs, which aren't even mentioned on the search result site anymore:

The Traefik container has to be attached to the same network as the containers to be exposed. If no networks are specified in the Docker Compose file, Docker creates a default one that allows Traefik to reach the containers defined in the same file.


So, why does traefik only work if containers are placed into the network traefik_default??
Thanks!

I am hitting the same issue, can you try running
docker inspect traefik_default

I suspect that what is happening is that traefik is using traefik_default no matter what I tell it to use, with the result that all other containers also need to be on the traefik_default network to be able to communicate with traefik
I suspect your solution to this is, if you are setting up traefik using docker compose then you need to add something like this to the service definition and a network definition to get it to use a network called, for example, web
    networks:
      - web

networks:
  web:
    attachable: true
    external: true
    name: web

